# Where's the implementation of #{exporterController.customExporter} in <pe:exporter> showcase

Tags: jsf, primefaces-extensions, exporter

I am building a Java application using the JSF PrimeFaces library. I don't want to use an open source PDF library to generate reports. I have been trying to figure out to use PrimeFaces Extensions data exporter to generate a PDF file with many data tables. I am talking about this link: [PrimeFaces Extensions](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/multipleTables.jsf)

However, I am having problem with this particular piece of code:

```
<p:panel header="Export PDF">  

                 <p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false">  

                     <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/pdf.png"/>  

                     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{exporterController.customExporter}" />  

                     <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="resumenTable,resumenTablePlan" fileName="example" datasetPadding="4"/>  

                 </p:commandLink>  

            </p:panel>
```

I can't seem to find the implementation of `#{exporterController.customExporter}`

Could somebody please guide me so that I can find the implementation of the customerExporter method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Primefaces extensions showcase did not show ExporterController source in [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf) there is no need for alarm as

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{exporterController.customExporter}" />
```

just sets Boolean value customExporter in ExporterController bean as false.

Anyways, the source for ExporterController is [here](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/showcase/blob/2bb4c72a6c3a68773c449000562e422397dcffaa/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/showcase/controller/ExporterController.java).

The full source code for extensions is [here](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/showcase)

You can request Oleg [here](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com/) in the comments section and he will gladly add this to showcase managed bean tab in case any other user is also confused.

Comment: I haven't tred it out. What I know is that I included the <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false" target="#{exporterController.customExporter}" /> and it gave me an error saying that it can't find that class. But I will try to remove it and see what happends.

Comment: I will check and I will let you know

Comment: I removed the <f:setPropertyActionListener> line and clicked on the pdf link and it is doing nothing. It is not downloading the pdf. There is something that my controller class needs to do that I am missing

Comment: I had a problem on my class path, indeed. I am able to download the pdf now. To your point, you did answer my question so there you go.